# How to fix 'differing rows' error in predict function?

Tags: r

I am trying to use the predict function but the output does not have the number of trials I expect. I assume something is wrong with my data.frame after reading other errors but can't figure it out.

I've tried to make sure my newdata has the same variable name as my model but that won't fix it. The differing rows are the differing number of solutions being found, for example I train over 50 different sets of information, and I test over 39950 sets.

In both the train_data and the test_data there are 10 columns which are the samples that will be included in each calculation. The model correctly finds these and names them test_data1, test_data2, etc.

I'm sure there is something I'm missing but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
trainingSampleSize <- k
sample_sample[[k-1]] <- sample(1:ncol(pre$train_data), k, replace = FALSE)
train_data <- pre$train_data[,sample_sample[[k-1]]]
test_data <- pre$test_data[,sample_sample[[k-1]]]
data_lm <- data.frame(train_data, pre$train_targets)
cvFitList[[(k-1)]] <- lm(pre$train_targets ~ train_data, data_lm)
prediction[[k-1]] <- predict(cvFitList[[(k-1)]], data.frame(train_data=test_data))
```

My goal is to get a prediction for every set of test_data, 39950 results from predict.

I got a warning message:

'newdata' had 39950 rows but variables found have 50 rows

and prediction[[k-1]] has only 50 rows

Comment: Please set `seed` and add a sample of your data.

Comment: I had this: set.seed(1) and lets say k = 2, a small piece of my data is:pre$train_data[1:5,130:131]
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 83.55713 137.5122
[2,] 82.33643 136.9019
[3,] 82.21436 136.6577
[4,] 82.03125 136.5356
[5,] 83.25195 137.5732
> pre$test_data[1:5,130:131]
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 70.00733 120.8496
[2,] 74.27979 127.2583
[3,] 74.70703 128.1128
[4,] 75.01221 128.3569
[5,] 74.82910 128.3569